# How to make a text-box accept only numeric characters?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

How to make a text-box accept only numeric characters (0-9) ? and give an error Message if it contains any alphabets or symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could catch the event `KeyDown` and check if `e.KeyCode` is numeric or not and discard it if you want.
Another thing you could try is using `IsNumeric(txt.Text)`.

Answer (score 3):

This `MSDN` article will help you:

- [How to: Create a Numeric Text Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regular Expression something like: ^(\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$
This will allow 0-11 digits left of the decimal and 0-2 digits right of the decimal.

If you have Ajax Controls you could use a Filtered Textbox Extender
`<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender8" runat="server" TargetControlID="YourTextBox" FilterType="Custom,Numbers" ValidChars="." >
                            </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>`

Or you could also try Marco's approach.

Comment: Also how can I allow the user to enter + and - symbols

Comment: @Failed_Noob are you using Visual Studio? If yes what Version? If no...then how are you creating the Winform?? Try taking a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996428.aspx

Comment: Dim myRegEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$") If myRegEx.IsMatch(YourTextBox.text) Then ' Is ok and allow the text that was entered Else ' Is not ok. then display an error message stating numbers only with 2 decimal places and '-' or '+'. End If

Comment: In the toolbox under validation drag and drop a regularexpressionvalidator to your form. in the properties for this control you can choose the control to validate: Your Text Box. Set Display to Static, Dynamic, None. add the validation expression:^(\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$. Set the ErrorMessage: This field can not be longer than 11 digits and 2 decimal places. etc. Your markup should look like:

Comment: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="YourTestBox"
 Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^(\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$ SetFocusOnError="True""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`
To test the reg. expression simply add text to the text box and remove the focus on the text box. The error message should display.
To allow the user to enter + and - symbols I thinkthe syntax for the regex is either:^([+-]?\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$ OR ^[+-]?(\d{0,11})(.\d{0,2})?$. I think the first one is correct.

Comment: @Erin No I didn't try. I am not familiar with RedEx.

Answer (score 1):

How about this will allow only numeric data and Back space

Under `Keypress` event

```
 if ((!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) && !(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i am with pincode textbox name an pin code and ID as txtPinCode

you just write on top of the code under document function starts 
lets write this code and check once

$("#<%=txtPincode.ClientID%>").numeric();

thanks 
akreddy

Answer (score 0):

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
    e.Handled = True
End If
```